# HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver

Tags: c#, mysql, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to create a connection with MySQL server using `FluentNHibernate` in ASP.NET Core, but I get an exception.

My Fluent configuration:

```
var config = Fluently.Configure()
                     .Database(MySQLConfiguration
                         .Standard
                         .ConnectionString(cs => cs
                             .Server(dbServer)
                             .Database(dbName)
                             .Username(dbUsername)
                             .Password(dbPassword)))
                     .Mappings(x =>x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
                     .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Exception:

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail."
```

InnerExceptions:

> HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver, NHibernate, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.
>
> TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Project config:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentNHibernate" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Iesi.Collections" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="6.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.Entity" Version="6.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Web" Version="6.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="NHibernate" Version="5.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Link to **deps.json**: http://pastebin.com/pn67pa6y

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FluentNHibernate` does not support .NET Core ([issue](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/361)), because `NHibernate` has not ([PR](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/633)).

`NHibernate` PR is scheduled for [v5.1](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/milestone/9), due by December 15, 2017 at the time of this writing.

**mstancombe** has a [fork](https://github.com/mstancombe/fluent-nhibernate/tree/NetCore) for .NET Core, but you have to build it yourself.